# How to write correct PHP echo tag for WordPress work?

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

I am new to PHP and was writing a condition while making WordPress website. I have writing the correct tag syntax but when I am converting it into PHP echo then it is showing error.

Both the tags are present in the jsfiddle link below.

[`Jsfiddle link`](https://jsfiddle.net/zxa4qu4j/)

Please let me know how to convert correct HTML code of the jsfiddle link to correct and working PHP code.

Comment: Oh dear: begging for urgency _and_ using backticks to circumvent the rule that fiddles need to be accompanied by code? That might acquire you some downvotes...

Answer (score 3):

In wordpress we can write php code in header.php , footer.php etc. files which are under the directory wordpress/wp-content or wordpress/wp-admin etc.

But if we want to use php code after login in wordpress I mean in page, post , widget etc. wordpress can't recognize those php code ().

So, please explain in which file are you writing both code. 
I'm damn sure that the code which is not working is inside the admin panel.

(Note : if you want to use condition through () inside admin panel (inside page,post etc.) ) you have to add a plugin like Exec-PHP (https://wordpress.org/plugins/exec-php/) or any other plugin which  executes PHP code in posts, pages and text widgets.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help

You added something in last like

```
";}?>
```

These are no needed

```
 <?php if (is_user_logged_in() ) {
                    echo "<a"; <?php if ( get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'dysaniaselect', true ) == 'dysania-link' && get_option('dysania_gridgallery_targetblank') == "true") { 
echo 'target="_blank"'; } ?> class="<?php echo( get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'dysaniaselect', true ) ); ?> <?php echo 'clbx' . $id; ?>" data-title="<?php the_title(); ?>" data-rel="<?php echo ( get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'dysaniaselect', true ) ) . 'clbx' . $id; ?>" href="<?php if (!empty($video)) { echo $video; } else { echo $imageurl; } ?>">
```

Comment: codes are present in jsfiddle link given above. 1 code is working fine but another php echo code is giving error. Need your help

Comment: i think this answer you need

Comment: can we put a <?php ?> inside <?php ?> tag? Your sample code is not working

Comment: this is the code that is working perfect and i want all this inside echo

<a <?php if ( get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'dysaniaselect', true ) == 'dysania-link' && get_option('dysania_gridgallery_targetblank') == "true") { 
    echo 'target="_blank"'; } ?> class="<?php echo( get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'dysaniaselect', true ) ); ?> <?php echo 'clbx' . $id; ?>" data-title="<?php the_title(); ?>" data-rel="<?php echo ( get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'dysaniaselect', true ) ) . 'clbx' . $id; ?>" href="<?php if (!empty($video)) { echo $video; } else { echo $imageurl; } ?>">

Comment: &lt;a  use this instead of <a